# Поведения генератора в ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Добрый Вечер. Разбираюсь с генераторами в ES6 и решил для примера написать небольшой пример "рекурсивного" генератора

```
function* f(val) {
  yield val;
  yield* f(val - 1);
}
const it = f(3);
console.log(it.next().value);
console.log(it.next().value);
console.log(it.next().value);
console.log(it.next().value);
```

Вывод в консоли меня немного удивил

```
  2
  0
 -2
 -4
```

Как я понял, генератор работает по принципу "достиг yield вышел из генератора с объектом". То есть получается :

1. Первая строка `console.log(it.next().value)` Здесь мы "разбудим" генератор и остановимся на `yield val` и выйдем из генератора, который будет спать, до следующего вызова. При этом `val` будет равно 3 и в консоли должно было вывести 3 соответственно. Здесь же уже изначально я ошибся.
2. Во второй строке `console.log(it.next().value)` как мне показалось мы передали генератору управление на самого себя, где значение `val` должно было стать 2 и опять дойти до строки `yield val`, а в консоли должно было вывести число 2. И т.д. в следующих пунктах.

Помогите пожалуйста понять, где я ошибся ?

Comment: Вроде всё работает как нужно: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xBm1b.png

Comment: Это в консоли, но если запускать код, то результат тот, который я написал выше.

Comment: А консоль выводит случайные числа? Она тоже код запускает. Сохранение Вашего кода в файл и запуск онного привёл к тому же, нормальному результату.

Comment: если не работает _код_ - стоит этот код добавить в вопрос. как уже выяснилось, тот что добавлен сейчас - работает корректно